# Programmatically close a jetty client

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jetty, google-oauth

I'm setting-up a **jetty** client that will be used to handle Google's **oauth2** authorization flow

```
com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver receiver =
                new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost(redirect_host).setPort(redirect_port).build();
```

This will **fail** if a previous authorization flow failed and *left the jetty client open*.

```
INFO [log:131] jetty-6.1.26
WARN [log:265] failed SocketConnector@180.200.105.100:8085: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
WARN [log:265] failed Server@32c65328: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Please, note that I'm using a **fixed url and port**.

Is there some way I can **check programmatically** whether or not the jetty client is **already open**, and handle this case, e.g by closing the previous jetty connection?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation using the google api to connect on youtube service, the connection is based upon the jetty client too.

I solved by putting my localServerReceiver object in a static class (to be honest, is a singleton Spring Bean) with default value "null", in the first try to connect, It create a new instance and store it in the static class attribute.

After this, before any new try to connect I call the method localServerReceiver.stop() to cancel any previous connection.

Soomething like this:

```
public class LocaServerReceiverRetriever{

private static LocalServerReceiver localServerReceiver = null;

public static LocalServerReceiver getLocalServerReceiver(){
    if(localServerReceiver == null){
        localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9001).build();
    }else{
        localServerReceiver.stop();
        localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9001).build();
    }
    return localServerReceiver ;
}
```

}

And then call "LocaServerReceiverRetriever.getLocalServerReceiver();" where is needed.

It works for me.
Good Luck

Comment: thanks for sharing!. Do you think this would work OK with a WebApp with multiple users/sessions, and multiple authorization requests ?